# How to remove Titlebar?

Tags: android, titlebar, android-windowmanager, android-window

I am trying to remove title bar from my activity but it is not getting removed.

Here is my code

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


    }
}
```

With or without the requestWindow line the output is the same then what is the  use of that line?

Comment: Just like this `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>`

Comment: In your manifest.xml file inside the Activity tag add this
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend editing your theme with no title bar. For example use of of these...

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></style>
<style name="Theme.FullScreen" 
parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></style>
```

Comment: I don't know. That is why I would your a style instead

Answer (score 1):

Apply this theme in your activity declared in the **Manifest File**.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding this to your manifest inside activity tag :

```
<activity
        android:name="your_app_packagename.activity_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

also try this in your activity :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in onCreate

```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: make sure you add that code after   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);`